# Obtaining an implicit solution to $\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{t+3x}{t-x}$ for $x(1) = 0, t \geq 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am asked to obtain an implicit solution to $\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{t+3x}{t-x}$ for $x(1) = 0, t \geq 0$. The equation is not seperable, but I don't immediately see another way to solve this equation. It looks easy so i'm sure the way to solve this is staring right at my face.

Can anyone offer some advice?

Comment: Try pulling out a $t$, and turning this into a homogeneous ODE. See if that works. Just a hunch.

Answer (score 1):

Hint...substitute $x=vt$ and the equation becomes separable in terms of $v$ and $t$

Comment: I let $x = vt$ so $\frac{dx}{dt} = v + t \frac{dv}{dt}$. Then $v + t \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{1+2v+v^2}{1-v}$. Rearranging, $\frac{1-v}{1+2v+v^2} = \frac{1}{t}dt$. Now solving I find $\ln(v^2 + 2v+1) = \ln(t) + C$. Raising by $\exp$, $(v+1)^2 = t^2 + e^{C}$. Then $v = t-1 + \sqrt[]{e^{C}}$. So $\frac{x}{t} = t-1+\sqrt[]{e^{C}}$. Hence, $x = t^2 - t + t\sqrt[]{e^{C}}$. But I think i've done something wrong since the $x(1)=0$ condition cannot be satisfied

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}\ln(v^2+2v+1)=\frac{2v+2}{v^2+2v+1}$ which has a different numerator than the one in the diff. equation. $\frac{1-v}{(1+v)^2}=\frac{2}{(1+v)^2}-\frac1{1+v}$.

Comment: @LutzL I do not understand your comment. Why are you differentiating by $t$ on $\ln(v^2 + 2v + 1)$?

Comment: Ah I dropped a sign, but still my answer seems to be incorrect.

Comment: @callkmo you haven't exponentiated correctly

Comment: You will get $-2\frac1{1+v}-\ln|1+v|=\ln|t|+C$, which can not be solved explicitly. It may be possible to get something using the LambertW function.